# Libgdx actor moveTo action is not working

Tags: java, android, libgdx, actor

I am trying to move actor on stage from point to point by actions and it is not working, i have tried for hours and it just not working, i will be glad for help..

I have searched by the internet for codes and all i tried didn't worked, i really dont understand what is wrong with this code, it is basically the same as a working one on a tutorial in the internet

the actor class:

```
public class Player extends Actor {

float x,y;
float screenWidth,screenHeight;
private Sprite sprite;
Texture image;
float width,height;
public Player(Texture image,float x, float  y,float width,float height, float screenWidth, float screenHeight)
{
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.screenWidth = screenWidth;
    this.screenHeight = screenHeight;

    this.image = image;
    sprite = new Sprite(image, 0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
    sprite.setPosition(x, y);

}

@Override
public float getX() {
    return x;
}

@Override
public void setX(float x) {
    this.x = x;
}

@Override
public float getY() {
    return y;
}

@Override
public void setY(float y) {
    this.y = y;
}

@Override
public float getWidth() {
    return width;
}

@Override
public void setWidth(float width) {
    this.width = width;
}

@Override
public float getHeight() {
    return height;
}

@Override
public void setHeight(float height) {
    this.height = height;
}

@Override
public void act(float delta) {
    super.act(delta);
}

@Override
public void draw (Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
    batch.draw(sprite,x,y,width,height);
}
}
```

and the main class:

```
            player = new Player(playerTexture,screenWidth/2,screenHeight-200,playerTexture.getWidth(),playerTexture.getHeight(),screenWidth,screenHeight);
 MoveToAction action = new MoveToAction();
        action.setPosition(300f,0f);
        action.setDuration(10f);
        player.addAction(action);

  @Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(orthographicCamera.combined);
    batch.begin();
    // batch.draw(playerTexture,10,10,10,10);

    batch.end();

    stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());

    stage.draw(); //this will call the batch to draw the sprite
}
```

Comment: What is not working? Can you see the player but it's not moving? Are you adding the player to the stage somehwere? I can't see that being done.

Comment: Yes i am adding him to the stage,i see the player but he is not moving.

Comment: You are overriding the setX and getX methods which are allready implemented by Actor. What happens if you remove instance variables x and y and the overriding versions of getX, getY, setX and so on?

Comment: That worked! , another question, i want it to move in a fixed speed and to not stop when it gets to the point but instead make it keep going in the same direction, any idea on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Actor already has x, y, width, and height fields. Since you created your own, you have hidden those parameters.

The source of your problem is that you failed to override `setPosition()` to use your fields. So the move action calls that and changes the fields that you have hidden and when you draw it, you are using your own fields that have not been changed.

Don't hide fields. It is very error-prone. You should delete the fields I mentioned above, along with all your overrides of getters and setters.

Here's a rule of thumb for OOP in general: if you are overriding any getter or setter without calling the super method, you are probably breaking something.

Unrelated, but you should be using TextureRegion instead of Sprite. A Sprite is a TextureRegion with additional parameters for size and position. Since those features are also in Actor, it is redundant and error-prone to use Sprite.